# Google Tag Manager: Texts malformed when sending dataLayer data to google analytics

Tags: encoding, special-characters, google-tag-manager

it seems I have some weird problem when google tag manager (GTM) is encoding texts from dataLayer and is sending them via POST request to google analytics collect endpoint.

The problem is with special slovak characters like á,í,ú,č etc. The html charset is set to UTF-8, when I check dataLayer object in console, all characters look okay, but when GTM sends out the date, then for example it encodes "dáta" as

`d%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%82%C3%83%C2%82%C3%82%C2%A1ta`

which is totally weird. With UTF-8 it should be encoded to `d%C3%A1ta`.

It seems like there are many weird characters added out of nowhere. And then of course when google analytics receive this it cannot parse to correct format and we see it there as

`dÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚ÂƒÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚ÂƒÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â‚ÃƒÂƒÃ‚Â‚ÃƒÂ‚Ã‚Â¡ta`

Any tips where to look for problem ? Google tag manager and encoding are not my strong areas...

edit: one more weird thing I noticed:

for example the slovak letter "á" should be encoded as "%C3%A1" .
What it seems to be doing is it split the encoded "á" to two parts "%C3" and "%A1" and then inserts long sequence of "%83%C2%83%C3%82%C2%83%C3" in between these two small parts.

Comment: This monstrosity if the result of applying UTF-8 encoding *seven* times in a row.

Comment: could you please clarify how exactly this value is passed to GA? meaning what's your tags and variables configuration?

Comment: @Botje hmm yes nice tip, I was able to replicate this by encoding to UTF-8 and then decoding using iso-8859-1 in loop multiple times, but how could this occur at google tag manager ? :D